# Автоматически сжимающийся div

Tags: css, css3

Имеется следующий код:

```css
.layer {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.messageBox {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid red;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="layer">
    <div class="messageBox">
        <p>TEXT</p>
        <p>TEXT</p>
        <p>TEXT</p>
        <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Этот код "накрывает" окно полупрозрачным слоем и по его центру выводит окошко. Всё прекрасно работает до тех пор, пока высота этого окошка (`div class="messageBox"`) невелика. Но как только число строк в нём становится достаточно большим, окошко по высоте превосходит рабочую область браузера и обрезается.

Требуется следующее поведение.

- Если окошко помещается внутри рабочей области браузера, то оно должно иметь минимальную высоту, т.е. не растягиваться по всей высоте рабочей области, а занимать минимально необходимое ему место.
- Если окошко имеет высоту бо́льшую, чем рабочая область браузера, то оно должно "вытянуться" во всю доступную высоту и иметь внутри себя полосу прокрутки. (Немаловажно, что полоса прокрутки должна быть именно внутри окошка, а не у рабочей области браузера!)

Как реализовать такое поведение? Желательно на "чистом" *CSS* (*CSS3*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подправлю и дополню предыдущий ответ:

```
.messageBox {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid red;
    flex-direction: column;

    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Ёлы-палы! Я знал, что всё просто! Полдня долбался, но про `max-height` не вспомнил... Спасибо огромное!

Comment: kff - position и display:flex; совместим ? по крайней мере это огромная ошибка https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox/#abspos-items

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте для .layer overflow-y: auto;

Comment: В этом случае полоса прокрутки появляется у окна браузера, а не у внутреннего `div`'а.

Comment: Да, но появляется она только тогда когда .messageBox уже занимает весь экран.

Comment: К сожалению, это не то поведение, которое нужно. Полоса прокрутки должна быть именно внутри `div`'а, у окна браузера её быть не должно.

Comment: Строго говоря она не у браузера, а у полупрозрачной подложки, просто подложка у вас величиной с окно браузера. Но да, это не совсем то, что вы просили. Ответ @Alex должен решить ваш вопрос. Но опять визуально разницы нет.

Comment: Ну да, согласен. Полоса у подложки. Устал за день, уже плоховато соображаю. :-(